# Fraction Value support in Verdana font

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, reportbuilder

I am using `Delphi XE4` and `Report Builder 15`. I have to change all the fonts in the report builder to Verdana. I am facing one issue while dealing with fraction values in the report. Following is my code sample:

```
var
AppFont: TLogFont;
....
....

AppFont.lfFaceName := 'Times Fraction';
```

It can show 1/2, 3/4 etc. in my reports. I have to change all the fonts in the reports to Verdana. When I changed above line as:

```
AppFont.lfFaceName := 'Verdana';
```

All the fraction values in the report started showing some garbage values.

Does Verdana support fractions? Please suggest.

Comment: What is Times Fraction? What character codes are you using?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Times Fraction is a font name.

Comment: Sigh, clearly that is so. What is special about it rather than Times? And how about answering my second question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am trying to figure out where character codes are defined. As far as I know, its utf-8.

Comment: That's an encoding. What we need to know is the actual Unicode character code. U+????  You must supply the text. What values are you supplying?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I cannot find where U+ thing is defined in the application. Is it related to windows?

Comment: I think you need to take a little time out and learn about Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode has a range of code points to represent vulgar fractions. For instance [VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF (U+00BD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bd/index.htm). This character has a perfectly decent glyph in the Verdana font that ships with Windows. And there are many other common vulgar fractions defined in the Unicode standard.

What I suspect you are doing is using a special font that contains fraction glyphs in code points that are not specified to contain fractions according to the Unicode standard. When you choose to do this you are committing yourself to use that font alone. That is a bad move. Where possible, stick to standards.

So I suggest that you stop using Times Fraction and stick to Unicode fonts using the Unicode code points for vulgar fractions.

Of course, if you need fractions that are not in the Unicode standard, then you need a different solution, one that does not attempt to use single glyphs from Verdana!

Comment: Thanks David, I understood what you are saying. But I further have one more problem now. Verdana only supports 3 fractions: 1/2, 1/4 and 3/4. But my application is using almost 30 fractions. For example 15/16 is used in my application and that is only supported by Times Fraction font and not by any other font. So, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Well, you are out of luck with Verdana. You'll need to use a font like Times Fraction, or render it some other way by composing it out of standard digits. That's tricky to do well. TeX is really what you want ....

Answer (score 1):

Does Verdana support fractions? Yes, it is completely support expressions like 1/2 1/3 etc.
Check you another settings.

Comment: What another settings?

Comment: First of all: Create a new project and check only this parameters. If you see that all is ok, then it may be a conflict with another properties of your first project.